# GStreamer issue with Raspbain Buster ans Pyside2

Tags: raspberry-pi, pyside, pyside2

I am trying to reproduce a video on a screen with a RPi. For the UI I am using the pyside2 library, and everything works fine on windows. however, when I try to run the same code in the RPi Zero W model, there seems to be an issue with the GStreamer library. My code is:

My code is:

```
class mainWindow(QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #IRRELEVANT CODE

        #VIDEO PLAYER CONFIG - Window1
        self.videoPlayer=QMediaPlayer()
        self.videoPlayer.setMedia(QUrl.fromLocalFile("file:///home/.../pyside2/VideoExample.avi"))

        #IRRELEVANT CODE

class QVideoWidget2(QVideoWidget): 
    """Auto-closing window"""
    def __init__(self, mainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: mainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1)) #QTimer.singleshot(10000, self.close)

def main():
    ex = mainWindow()
    ex.videoPlayer.play() #Reproduces the video
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

However, the following errors pop up and the application is not initialised:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QVideoWidget2::supportedFormatsChanged()

ERROR: Caught a segmentation fault while loaging plugin file: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgsttypefinsfunctions.so
Please aither:
- remove it and restart
- run with --gst-disable-segtrap --gst-disable-registry-fork and debug
```

I've tried to remove and reinstall Gstreamer but I cannot fins any solution. Does anybody have any idea?

Additional info:

RPi OS: `cat /etc/os-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Gstream version: `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version`

```
GStreamer Core Library version 1.14.4
```

Comment: Possibly related to this report: [PYSIDE-864](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-864). What Qt version do you have? Can you update it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I finally solved my issue by using another class instead of a one depending on QVideoWidget. I don't know why I had so many issues between GStreamer and this specific widget.. anyway, another option worked fine. Thanks!